# Add holidays row in fullcalendar like google calendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I use fullcalendar lib in my project. Now I want to add a holiday row like google calendar like this below image. Can I do that? and how?

[image]

Comment: Even though it might be obvious to you, it would be better to add more context, like which library to be used, what you have tried, what error you were getting, etc. At the very least it might help other visitors recognize they might have a similar problem, or even might have a solution.

Comment: Which version of fullcalendar are you using?

Answer (score 0):

First, create a function which return an object with all the holidays days for a year for example

```js
function Holidays(y) {

    var chrstimasDay = new Date(an, "11", "25")

    //Add others holdays days here

    return new Object([{
            title: "Christmas Day's",
            start: moment(chrstimasDay).format("L")
          }
          //Add others holdays days here
        }
```

Then add this source in your fullcalendar

```js
$("#yourDivId").fullCalendar({
    //init your options....
  
            eventSources: [
            {
             events: Holidays(moment().format('YYYY')),
             color: "#000",
             className: "Add extra classname here for customization"
         }
  })
```